# How to switch to an iframe whose id is stored in a variable in karate?

Tags: karate

In my application, I have an iframe whose id is dynmaic. So i could fetch that using

```
* def linkElement = locate(("//*[contains(@id, 'flex-microform-')]"))
* print linkElement
* def linkValue = linkElement.property('id')
* print linkValue
```

Now, I need to switchFrame() using that value as id.
Can someone let me know how I can do it please?

Tried `switchFrame(linkValue)` but it is using that just a value and not an id..

Actual - "params":{"nodeId":1,"selector":"flex-microform-07wLRuVpIeOl7QUQJaTsaVl3bOyDOtTv"}

Expected - "params":{"nodeId":1,"selector":"#flex-microform-07wLRuVpIeOl7QUQJaTsaVl3bOyDOtTv"}

I want the value in linkValue to be considered as id value in switchFrame.

Is that possible?

Comment: hint: `switchFrame('#' + linkValue)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @PeterThomas, it worked... yay!!!!